# Rewrite URL for only archive page (custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, template-hierarchy, archive-template

There is a few Q/A about custom post URL rewrite but I haven't found any simple answer to what I'm trying to achieve.

My CTP is "event" and **I have the current page structure that I want to preserve**:

- `siteurl.com/agenda`
- `siteurl.com/event/event-slug`

Right now in my theme I use two files `single-event.php` and `page-agenda.php`. The latter is the archive page, because I want my archive post slug to be `siteurl.com/agenda` and not `siteurl.com/event` so I've created an additional page on my backend.

It's working like that but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant solution to only rewrite my CPT archive page URL while using the proper `archive-event.php` template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a separate slug for the post type archive by setting the slug as the value for the `has_archive` argument, instead of just `true`:

```
register_post_type(
    'event',
    array(
        'has_archive' => 'agenda',
        // etc.
    )
);
```

Now you can use `single-event.php` and `archive-event.php` for the single and archive views, but the URL for the archive will be `siteurl.com/agenda`.

Comment: Perfect, it's that simple! Thank you Jacob